# Could I use the first letter as $ in a variable in c#?

Tags: c#

I called the `$id` variable and it appears me in the console after building: "error is not valid for a member of the class, struct or interface to the declaration".

Has anyone run into this type of error before or know how to bypass this issue?

The code is as follows:

```
string $id = "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx";
```

Comment: What's the issue? Just don't use illegal characters in identifiers. The compiler won't let you.

Comment: Yes, ok I understand. It is the fast and simple way but is there any sort of escape?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure you do understand, because I'm telling you that the compiler won't let you do that.

Comment: You can use `@` to escape any reserved keyword like `@for`

Comment: @Xiaoy312 I tried to use the @ but it doesn't work.

Comment: only through reflection. You can have space in your identifier name too, if you only edit/read it through reflection

Comment: You cannot use restricted syntax to start variables. Also this implies you're going against general C# style

Comment: The answer is no, you cannot declare a variable in C# containing the `$` character in the name.

Comment: @ntohl How can I use the reflection? Could you explain better?

Comment: Why do you need a variable to have precisely that name? Is it a class member that is serialized/deserialized into a structure that has that name? If so, your serialization library will have ways of specifying a different name for the field.

Comment: I need it because I have to handle a data structure with this $id.

Comment: This starts sounding a bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... How does _"handling a data structure"_ force you to use specific names for your variables? Why cant you just name the variable "id"? Are you maybe trying to generate code from your data?

Comment: How can I fix this question? because it is limiting me to produce a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO I highly discourage to use something like this, but you can still name your properties with illegal characters. Usage of the properties are the same painful as generating them>

```
var assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("MyAssembly"),
    AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
var modulBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MyModul");
var longType = typeof(long);
TypeBuilder typeBuilder = modulBuilder.DefineType("MyObjectChild", TypeAttributes.Class);
FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineField("m_$id", longType, FieldAttributes.Private);
var propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty("$id", PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, longType, null);
MethodAttributes propertyAttributes = MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig;
MethodBuilder getBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("get_$id", propertyAttributes, longType, Type.EmptyTypes);
ILGenerator getGen = getBuilder.GetILGenerator();
getGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
getGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
getGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

//set method
MethodBuilder setBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("set_$id", propertyAttributes, null, new [] { longType });
ILGenerator setGen = setBuilder.GetILGenerator();
setGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
setGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
setGen.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);
setGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setBuilder);
propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getBuilder);
var createdType = typeBuilder.CreateType();
var childObject = Activator.CreateInstance(createdType, BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, new object[0],
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var myNewType = childObject.GetType();
foreach (var propertyInfo in myNewType.GetProperties())
{
    // you can see the $id property there.
    Console.WriteLine(propertyInfo.Name);
}
```

Please check out first if your imported classes may give you a functionality to rename your properties at least C# side.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply but I would like to tell the others that I do not agree with the treatment they gave me. I was considered an idiot. I want to say this because they have tried to ridicule me several times, but fortunately, two people have given a relevant answer to the question. I'm a professional and I'm not here to tease anyone.

Comment: ;) Be kind and always hear out the silent ones also

Comment: I'll try to do my best. Thank you so much. :P

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot do that.

$ is not a legal character in C# identifiers.

There is no way to circumvent that in C#.

---

The exact rules for C# identifiers are laid out on this page - [C# Identifier Names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/identifier-names).

Basically:

- Identifiers must start with a letter, or _.
- Identifiers may contain Unicode letter characters, decimal digit characters, Unicode connecting characters, Unicode combining characters, or Unicode formatting characters. For more information on Unicode categories, see the Unicode Category Database. You can declare identifiers that match C# keywords by using the @ prefix on the identifier. The @ is not part of the identifier name. For example, @if declares an identifier named if. These verbatim identifiers are primarily for interoperability with identifiers declared in other languages.

$ falls outside of these rules, and it thus not allowed.